# Python reading a text file but prints nothing

Tags: python

I tried different methods of printing out the text file. But it doesn't print anything.
There is code in the text file for sure, and I am spelling it right.
Why doesn't it print anything from the text file?

```
f = open("quotes.txt", "r")
print("Name of the file:", f.name)

line = f.readline()
print("Read Line: %s" % line)

data = f.read()
print("Data: ", data)

f.close()
```

This is what it prints:

```
Name of the file: quotes.txt
Read Line:
Data:
```

Comment: Your code is right on my machine. Maybe the file you want to read is empty...

Comment: I "solved" it by deleting everything in the text file and write it to the text. Then I could finally read the text from there. Messed up but atleast I can write whats in there...